# Odata & Android & Sync Framework 4.0

Tags: android, frameworks, synchronization, odata

Has anyone tried using the new Sync Framework 4.0 with Android. I have tried the web, but there are no samples available as of now. I want to check before converting client.Services (CacheController) sample provided in wm 6.5 to Java. Any help/samples for me to move in the right direction?

Thanks
Shankar.

Answer (score 9):

try [my sample](http://esilo.pl/ListSynSample.zip)

EDIT:

i moved samples [here](http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Yesterday I found the same - modified the code and it has started yielding good results. I am going to work on the same today as well. Probably should be done by today.

Comment: @Shankar so it will be nice if you'll accept my answer ... i spent a lots of houres to made this sample ... remeber that it is not complited ... u need to add conflict resolving code